# No ejecuta la acción del botón por defecto después de pulsar ENTER

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Verán tengo el siguiente problema:

tengo un sistema de búsqueda de productos el cual devuelve el resultado de la función al memento que el lector de código de barras. pasa el valor:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import uic,QtCore,QtNetwork,QtGui
from PIL import Image

from Fire import *


class Secundaria(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("busqueda.ui",self)



        self.limpiar_s.clicked.connect(self.limpiar)
        self.busqueda_s.clicked.connect(self.obtener_info)# Boton de busqueda


    def limpiar(self):
        self.id_s.clear()
        self.bar_s.clear()
        self.pro_s.clear()
        self.pre_s.clear()
        self.mar_s.clear()
        self.exe1_s.clear()
        self.exe2_s.clear()
        self.exe3_s.clear()
        self.label_imagen_diag.clear()

    def obtener_info(self):


        if self.id_s.text() != "":

            self.busqueda(self.id_s.text())

        elif self.bar_s.text() != "":

            self.busqueda_bar(self.bar_s.text())

    def busqueda_bar(self,single_bar):

        ref = db.reference("/Productos_Bar/"+str(single_bar))
        r0 = ref.get()


        for key in r0.items():

            if key[0] == 'id':
                self.id_s.setText(key[1])
            elif key[0] == 'producto':
                self.pro_s.setText(key[1])
            elif key[0] == 'precio':
                self.pre_s.setText(' $ '+str(key[1]))
            elif key[0] == 'marca':
                self.mar_s.setText(key[1])
            elif key[0] == 'exe1':
                self.exe1_s.setText(str(key[1]))
            elif key[0] == 'exe2':
                self.exe2_s.setText(str(key[1]))                
            elif key[0] == 'exe3':
                self.exe3_s.setText(str(key[1]))
            elif key[0] == 'url':
                url = key[1]
                manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
                manager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
                manager.get(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url)))

    def busqueda(self,single):
        status =0
        refbus = db.reference('/Productos_Bar/')
        r1 = refbus.get()
        for key in r1.items():
            res1 = key[1]['id']
            if res1 == single:
                new_ref = key[0]
                status =1
        if status ==1:
            self.bar_s.setText(new_ref)
            self.busqueda_bar(new_ref)
        else:
            self.id_s.setText("Id No Encontrado")


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtNetwork.QNetworkReply)
    def onFinished(self,reply):
        image = QtGui.QImage.fromData(reply.readAll())
        if not image.isNull():
            pixi = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image).scaled(150,150)
            self.label_imagen_diag.setPixmap(pixi)
            self.label_imagen_diag.resize(150,150)






app = QApplication([])
s = Secundaria()
s.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo al utilizarlo en otro código ya no se ejecuta la acción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtNetwork, QtCore, QtGui, Qt
import webbrowser
from Firebase_load import *


class Inicio(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Interfaces/Inicio.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)

        self.l_busqueda.setFocus() #label para ingresar el codigo
        self.b_busqueda.clicked.connect(self.obtener_info)# boton que iniciar la funcion de busqueda

    def obtener_info(self):
        if self.l_busqueda.text() !="":
            self.busqueda(self.l_busqueda.text())

    def busqueda(self,codigo):
        if len(codigo) > 4:
            print("bar")
            self.busqueda_bar(codigo)

        else:
            ref  = db.reference('/Productos_Bar')
            r1 = ref.get()
            for key in r1.items():
                respuesta = key[1]['id']
                if respuesta == codigo:
                    nueva_ref = key[0]
                    self.busqueda_bar(nueva_ref)
                    self.l_busqueda.setText(codigo)
                    break
                else:
                    self.l_busqueda.setText('ID no encontrado')

    def busqueda_bar(self,code):
        ref_bus = db.reference('/Productos_Bar/'+str(code))
        refb = ref_bus.get()
        try:
            for key in refb.items():
                if key[0] == 'producto':
                    self.l_producto.setText(key[1])
                elif key[0] == 'precio':
                    self.l_precio.setText('$ '+str(key[1]))
                elif key[0] == 'marca':
                    self.l_marca.setText(key[1])
                elif key[0] == 'exe1':
                    self.x1.setText(str(key[1]))
                elif key[0] == 'exe2':
                    self.x2.setText(str(key[1]))
                elif key[0] == 'exe3':
                    self.x3.setText(str(key[1]))
                elif key[0] == 'url':
                    url = key[1]
                    manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
                    manager.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
                    manager.get(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url)))
                elif key[0] == 'id':
                    global _id
                    _id = key[1]
        except:
            self.l_busqueda.setText('Bar_code no definido')


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtNetwork.QNetworkReply)
    def onFinished(self,reply):
        image = QtGui.QImage.fromData(reply.readAll())
        if not image.isNull():
            pixi = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image).scaled(150,150)
            self.l_imagen.setPixmap(pixi)
            self.l_imagen.resize(150,150)



app = QApplication([])
i = Inicio()
i.show()
app.exec_()
```

> **Nota**: dentro de QTDesigner, el botón busqueda del primer codigo esta definido como `autoDefault`. Ya apliqué ese cambio al segundo código pero no funciona tampoco.

¿Qué es lo que sucede?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El [botón por defecto](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#default-button) **es un comportamiento exclusivo de `QDialog`** que permite que un botón sea automáticamente activado cuando se pulsa <kbd>ENTER</kbd> en el mismo. En tu segundo ejemplo usas `QMainWindows` como clase base, por lo que aunque definas el botón como `default` no va a funcionar, esto es solo una propiedad del botón pero carece de efecto porque `QMainWindow` no implementa este comportamiento.

Por lo tanto, o usas un `QDialog` o bien deberás manejar el evento adecuadamente tu mismo. Podrías hacer que al pulsar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> en cualquier parte de la ventana active el botón de búsqueda, pero lo lógico es que esto solo ocurra cuando el foco esté en la "sección de búsqueda" de la ventana. Puedes usar [`eventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html) para ello, llamando a `self.obtener_info` solo cuando esto ocurra en los widgets encargados de la búsqueda.

Te dejo un ejemplo simple, en este caso la "sección de búsqueda" está englobada en un `QFrame`, desconozco la estructura de tu App, pero puedes asignar el `eventFilter` a todos los widgets en los que pulsar <kbd>ENTER</kbd> ejecute `self.obtener_info`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets



class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.vender_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget, text="Vender")
        self.vender_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 530, 88, 34))
        self.buscar_frm = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.buscar_frm.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 751, 241))
        self.buscar_frm.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.buscar_frm.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.nombre_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.buscar_frm)
        self.nombre_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 130, 58, 18))
        self.nombre_ent = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.buscar_frm)
        self.nombre_ent.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 120, 271, 32))
        self.buscar_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.buscar_frm, text="Buscar")
        self.buscar_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 90, 88, 34))
        self.id_ent = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.buscar_frm)
        self.id_ent.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 60, 271, 32))
        self.id_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.buscar_frm)
        self.id_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 70, 58, 18))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.buscar_btn.clicked.connect(self.buscar)
        self.buscar_frm.installEventFilter(self)


    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
                self.buscar()
                return True
        return QtWidgets.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, obj, event)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def buscar(self):
        print("Buscando...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```